# I am getting error while trying to update my existing eclipse IDE. Would like to prevent a complete unistall the reinstall

Tags: eclipse

I was trying to update my existing eclipse IDE by using the check updates option. But I got the following error while trying to install the updates. For some reasons I would really like to avoid uninstalling current IDE and then re-installing the new one. The error log is as follows:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=C__Users_User_eclipse_java-2021-06_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
OK
Public key not found for 8074478291308066379.
OK
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
OK
Public key not found for 8074478291308066379.
OK
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.lucene.analyzers-common,8.4.1.v20221112-0806
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.sshd.osgi,2.9.2.v20221117-1942
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
OK
Public key not found for 8074478291308066379.
OK
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
OK
Public key not found for 8074478291308066379.
OK
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
OK
Public key not found for 8074478291308066379.
OK
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
OK
Public key not found for 8074478291308066379.
OK
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
OK
Public key not found for 8074478291308066379.
OK
Result of processing steps.
OK
OK
OK
Public key not found for 8074478291308066379.
OK
```

I was trying to update my existing eclipse IDE by using the check updates option. But I got an error while trying to install the updates.

Comment: Where and when is this error exactly shown (in the update dialog?)? Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_.

Answer (score 6):

No need to reinstall. To work around this problem, go to `Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites` and disable the following two entries:

- Latest Eclipse IDE Packages Release.
- Latest Eclipse Simultaneous Release.

[image: Settings window]

That's what worked for me. I installed WindowBuilder from the downloaded zip file afterwards.

Comment: But that would prevent the update of Eclipse itself.

Comment: @AlexanderRühl This is but a workaround. You can update Eclipse when you have time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this just now by re-installing the latest version of Eclipse over my existing version.

Comment: If you don't use the Eclipse Installer, extract the ZIP archive into an empty folder, not into an existing installation.