# How to resolve public key error while installing e(fx) 3.8.0 eclipse plugin on linux?

Tags: linux, eclipse, javafx, plugins

I'm trying to install e(fx) 3.8.0 eclipse plugin via "install new ..." menu

I use VMVirtualToolsBox to run a Rocky 8.5 and 4.22 Eclipse version.
I 'm trying at home and proxy is desactivated

efx plugin 3.8 install works with a 2nd VM (4.22 eclipse) and not this one

I also tried with 3.7 ... 3.3 and its the same
Install starts well but stops at 50% diplaying this message :

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed  session
> context was:(profile=epp.package.jee,
> phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
> action=). Result of processing steps. OK OK OK Public key not found
> for 810cecf8ba271228. OK Result of processing steps. OK OK OK Public
> key not found for 810cecf8ba271228. OK

Error log View :

> org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException:
> org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKey found where PGPPublicKeyRing
> expected  at
> org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyRingCollection.(Unknown
> Source)   at
> org.bouncycastle.openpgp.bc.BcPGPPublicKeyRingCollection.(Unknown
> Source)   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.processors.pgp.PGPSignatureVerifier.readPublicKeys(PGPSignatureVerifier.java:176)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.processors.pgp.PGPSignatureVerifier$PGPPublicKeyStore.addKeys(PGPSignatureVerifier.java:60)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.processors.pgp.PGPSignatureVerifier.initialize(PGPSignatureVerifier.java:130)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.addPGPSignatureVerifier(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:496)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.addPostSteps(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:483)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.processDestination(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:1151)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:791)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.getArtifact(MirrorRequest.java:328)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transferSingle(MirrorRequest.java:298)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transfer(MirrorRequest.java:234)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.perform(MirrorRequest.java:156)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:779)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.DownloadJob.run(DownloadJob.java:64)
> at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

What does it means , what can i change to solve this ?

Is there a way to download an e(fx) file to install it localy ?

I also tried to update eclipse version to 4.27 without success, this attemp generates the same kind of problem

error log :

> org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException:
> org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKey found where PGPPublicKeyRing
> expected  at
> org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPublicKeyRingCollection.(Unknown
> Source)   at
> org.bouncycastle.openpgp.bc.BcPGPPublicKeyRingCollection.(Unknown
> Source)   at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.processors.pgp.PGPSignatureVerifier.readPublicKeys(PGPSignatureVerifier.java:176)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.processors.pgp.PGPSignatureVerifier$PGPPublicKeyStore.addKeys(PGPSignatureVerifier.java:60)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.processors.pgp.PGPSignatureVerifier.initialize(PGPSignatureVerifier.java:130)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.addPGPSignatureVerifier(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:496)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.addPostSteps(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:483)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.processDestination(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:1151)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:791)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.getArtifact(MirrorRequest.java:328)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transferSingle(MirrorRequest.java:298)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.transfer(MirrorRequest.java:234)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.MirrorRequest.perform(MirrorRequest.java:156)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.SimpleArtifactRepository.getArtifact(SimpleArtifactRepository.java:779)
> at
> org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.artifact.repository.simple.DownloadJob.run(DownloadJob.java:64)
> at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

session data :

> eclipse.buildId=4.22.0.I20211124-1800 java.version=17.0.1
> java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium BootLoader constants: OS=linux,
> ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=fr_FR Framework arguments:  -product
> org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product Command-line arguments:  -os linux
> -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

Comment: Please go to the _Error Log_ view, select the error, hit Ctrl+C and paste it into your question formatted as _Sample Code_. Eclipse 4.22 is 5 releases behind. Please upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, I use VM and one works with 4.22 and the 2nd not. 
I tried to update to 4.27 and it seems to be the same kind of error. it 's possible with 2nd and not the first.
I edited original question to post error logs

Comment: This is hard to read because you formatted it as a quote instead of sample code, so all the line breaks are lost. The session data are part of the error message and shows that your Eclipse have not been upgraded, being still five releases behind. The logged stack traces are about PGP encryption via BouncyCastle used for verify what will be installed (p2). Please try a fresh installation of Eclipse 2023-03 (4.27).

Answer (score 2):

To work around this problem, go to Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites and disable the following two entries:

Latest Eclipse IDE Packages Release.
Latest Eclipse Simultaneous Release.

reference link: [I am getting error while trying to update my existing eclipse IDE. Would like to prevent a complete unistall the reinstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75343481/)