# Eclipse throws an error when I try to set up Wildfly

Tags: eclipse, wildfly

Whenever I try to set up Wildfly via *Window -> Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environments -> Add -> Red Hat JBoss Middleware -> JBoss AS, WildFly & EAP Server Tools* Eclipse shows the following error:

[image]

This error also occurs when I try to install TM Terminal or JBoss Tools from the Eclipse Marketplace It also occured when I checked for updates, but I was able to resolve the error in this instance by unchecking two entries in the Available Software Sites as shown here: [I am getting error while trying to update my existing eclipse IDE. Would like to prevent a complete unistall the reinstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75343481/i-am-getting-error-while-trying-to-update-my-existing-eclipse-ide-would-like-to)

I'm using Eclipse 2021-12 Enterprise.

Comment: Eclipse 2021-12 is six releases behind. Please upgrade. Please support the open source software you use by not asking questions about outdated versions, but about the latest version only.

Comment: After Eclipse 2021-12 Ant-builds with Java8 were removed. Some of us still need these options.

Comment: @Mathias Some of you should better get involved. And you can also run Ant builds with any Java version as an _External Tool_ command line _Program_.